# Serialization in Scala

Tags: scala, serialization

Im trying to understand basics of serialization in Scala. When i run the first example below I get the following output on the last line: `res1: A.Mao = A$$anonfun$main$1$Mao$1@78e67e0a`

```
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class Poo(val aa:Int) extends Serializable {
    override def toString() = "Hola"
}
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class Mao(val hi: Poo) extends Serializable

def serialize() = {
    val test = new Mao(new Poo(1))
    try{
        val fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\misc\\address.ser");
        val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(test);
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
  }catch {
    case ex => ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}                                                 
serialize()                                       

def ReadObjectFromFile[A](filename: String)(implicit m:scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A = {
  val input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))
  val obj = input.readObject()
  obj match {
    case x if m.erasure.isInstance(x) => x.asInstanceOf[A]
    case _ => sys.error("Type not what was expected when reading from file")
  }
}                                                 


ReadObjectFromFile[Mao]("c:\\misc\\address.ser")
```

If I change the example and use `case classes` instead things works as expected with the output

```
res1: A.Mao = Mao(Hola)

case class Poo(val aa:Int) {
    override def toString() = "Hola"
}

case class Mao(val hi: Poo)

def serialize() = {
    val test = new Mao(new Poo(1))
    try{
        val fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\misc\\address.ser");
        val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(test);
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
  }catch {
    case ex => ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}                                                 

def ReadObjectFromFile[A](filename: String)(implicit m:scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A = {
  val input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))
  val obj = input.readObject()
  obj match {
    case x if m.erasure.isInstance(x) => x.asInstanceOf[A]
    case _ => sys.error("Type not what was expected when reading from file")
  }
}                                                 

ReadObjectFromFile[Mao]("c:\\misc\\address.ser")
```

So my questions are: 
What do I need to do to get class to give the same output as case class?

Why does case class work without adding any explicit information about serialization?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the de/serialization (which seems correct) - it's just the way the result is *displayed*:

Scala REPL (and Worksheets) use the value's `toString` method to display it. Case classes override the default `toString()` method, therefore the output is displayed nicely (as expected). For non-case classes, the defeault implementation of `Object.toString()` is called, and results in the class name and address that you see.

You can implement `toString` for the non-case class too, to get the same result:

```
class Mao(val hi: Poo) extends Serializable {
  override def toString = s"Mao($hi)"
}

// program prints:
// Done
// Mao(Hola)
```